# Difference between Vlookup returning 0 and #n/a?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I was wondering why my Vlookup function will sometimes return 0 and sometimes return #N/A when it is unable to find the value.

I know how to work around this but was just curious as to why it doesn't return all #N/A's or all zeroes

Thank you!

Comment: It will return `0` if the value is found in the lookup column but the return cell is blank.  It will return `#N/A` when the lookup value is not found in the lookup column and the forth criterion is FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

NA is returned when the `lookup_value` is not found

0 is returned when the `lookup_value` is found, but the `col_index_number` is blank.

The formula is as follows:
`=VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

lookup value being your matching statement

col index num being the location within the column you are attempting to return data from.

For instance, lets say you are comparing a list of ID's via your `lookup_value` and attempting to return the price via the `col_index_num`. If the ID exists but there is no price, this will return 0. However, if the ID does not exist at all in your comparison, it will return #N/A.